# Estimator bias and consistency

Tags: statistics, self-learning, estimation

> Let $x_1, x_2, \ldots,x_n$ be a simple random sample from a random variable $X$ with support $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ and probability function $p(0)=\frac{5}{12}(1-\lambda)^2$, $p(1)=\lambda$, $p(2)=\lambda(1-\lambda)$, $p(3)=\frac{1}{3}(1-\lambda)^2$ and $p(4)=\frac{1}{4}(1-\lambda)^2$, where $\lambda$ is a parameter $\in(0,1)$.
>
> Is this estimator
>   $$\hat \lambda=1+\frac{n}{n+1}-\bar X$$
>
> unbiased and consistent for $\lambda$? $\bar X$ is sample mean.

The expectation of $X$ is:

$$\mathbb{E}(X)=0\cdot\frac{5}{12}(1-\lambda)^2+1\cdot\lambda+2\cdot\lambda(1-\lambda)+3\cdot\frac{1}{3}(1-\lambda)^2+4\cdot\frac{1}{4}(1-\lambda)^2=2-\lambda$$

Now, the expectation of $\hat \lambda$ should be:

$$\mathbb{E}(\hat \lambda)=\mathbb{E}\left(1+\frac{n}{n+1}-\bar X\right)=1+\frac{n}{n+1}-(2-\lambda)$$

thus the estimator is biased.

For consistency we need $\lim_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{E}(\hat \lambda)=\lambda$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{Var}(\hat \lambda)=0$, so:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{E}(\hat \lambda)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(1+\frac{n}{n+1}-(2-\lambda)\right)=\lambda$$

How can I find $\mathbb{Var}(\hat \lambda)$?

**First edit**

Based on Michael's suggestion:

$\mathbb{Var}(X)=\mathbb{E}(X^2)-(\mathbb{E}(X))^2=\left(0\cdot\frac{5}{12}(1-\lambda)^2+1^2\cdot\lambda+2^2\cdot\lambda(1-\lambda)+3^2\cdot\frac{1}{3}(1-\lambda)^2+4^2\cdot\frac{1}{4}(1-\lambda)^2\right)-(2-\lambda)^2=3-5\lambda+2\lambda^2$.

$\mathbb{Var}(\widehat\lambda)=\dfrac{3-5\lambda+2\lambda^2}{n}$ so $\lim_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{Var}(\hat \lambda)=0$

Comment: Since $\widehat\lambda$ is a constant minus $X$, the variance of $\widehat\lambda$ is the same as the variance of $X$. $\qquad$

Comment: The estimator $\widehat\lambda$ is biased but it's asymptotically unbiased, as you've shown. $\qquad$

Comment: Ok, $\mathbb{Var}(X)=\mathbb{E}(X^2)-(\mathbb{E}(X))^2$, so $\mathbb{Var}(X)=\left(0\cdot\frac{5}{12}(1-\lambda)^2+1^2\cdot\lambda+2^2\cdot\lambda(1-\lambda)+3^2\cdot\frac{1}{3}(1-\lambda)^2+4^2\cdot\frac{1}{4}(1-\lambda)^2\right)-(2-\lambda)^2=3-5\lambda+2\lambda^2$ then $\mathbb{Var}(\widehat\lambda)=3-5\lambda+2\lambda^2$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{Var}(\hat \lambda)$ is not zero.

Comment: It appears that a typesetting problem arose in your comment that result from too many consecutive non-blank spaces in MathJax code.  If you change that before the five minutes are up, you can fix it.

Comment: That problem apparently doesn't afflict MathJax code in questions or answers, but it does in comments.

Comment: It looks as if you computed the variance of a single observation, which does not depend on $n$ at all, rather than the variance of the estimator.  The variance of the estimator does approach $0$ as $n$ grows. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I think now is correct :-)